# Asus Zenbook 13 UX333FN_RX333FN "Wi-fi adapter not found" (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, intel

I've reinstalled my ubuntu a week ago and I've been unable to get my wifi adapter to work. (Single Boot: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
I'd love some help to troubleshoot/find a solution as I'm at a complete loss at the moment.
Here is some more information from certain commands I've run so far.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0000]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
uname -r
```

5.15.0-41-generic

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

No response

```
rfkill
```

| ID | TYPE | DEVICE | SOFT | HARD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | wlan | asus-wlan | unblocked | unblocked |
| 1 | bluetooth | asus-bluetooth | unblocked | unblocked |
| 2 | bluetooth | hci0 | unblocked | unblocked |

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

```
[    2.193539] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.199789] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 9df0/0000, rev=0x318, rfid=0x0
[    2.199908] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

```
sudo dkms status
```

No response

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: I've added the new command output, and it's a single boot system (Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: Please add output of `dkms status`. Please format output properly using the `{}` icon above.

Comment: Generally it is a kernel bug if you didn't manually install any backports.

Comment: There is no response when I use ```dkms status```

Comment: So it is a kernel bug. You can report it to Launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux`. This device used to work with previous kernels.

Comment: Alright, I will report it to launchpad, thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)